# Is it possible to access winform listview class from my new class library?

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

This is my first time trying to create a DLL, where one of its classes contains a method that will copy data from datatable to listview. I cannot find listview class and I cannot include the namespace of windows.forms. My question would be is it even possible to do this? or are there suggestion what other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why can't you reference forms?

Comment: You can "Add Reference, Assemblies"  `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: But  that does make it a WinForms library. Do think about separating your logic into layers.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Got it! Thank you! Life saver!

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff Only if you are creating a .NET Framework Class Library.